# Extracting data using BeautifulSoup and a loop

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The data I need is enclosed between two HTML comments. The first is "Data starts here" and the second is "Data ends here"

I've figured out how to get the next line after the comment, but I need the one after, and the one after that, until it hits the "Data ends here" comment.

Here's my attempt at writing a loop for it. However, that just enters an infinite loop of printing the first line after the comment.

I don't know how many lines will be between the two comments, so it needs to be a while loop. Any tips? I think I'm close. I'm just not knowledgable with BeautifulSoup 4 yet.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")

for comment in soup.findAll(text=lambda text:isinstance(text, Comment)):
    if comment.strip() == 'Data starts here':
        while comment.next_element.strip() != 'Data ends here':
            print(comment.next_element.strip())
```

EDIT:

```
</div>
<p clear="both">
<b>Data at: 0734 UTC 27 Jan 2017</b></p>
<!-- Data starts here --> KJXN 270656Z AUTO 30012KT 10SM SCT026 OVC033 00/M04 A2980 RMK AO2 SNE0558 SLP100   P0000 T00001044<br/><hr width="65%"/> KTEW 270724Z AUTO 27008KT 10SM OVC040 00/M04 A2979 RMK AO2 T00001042<br/><hr width="65%"/>
<!-- Data ends here -->
<br clear="both" style="clear:both;"/>
</div> <!-- awc_main_content -->
</div> <!-- awc_main -->
```

WEBSITE LINK: https://www.aviationweather.gov/metar/data?ids=KJXN%20KDTW%20KLAN&format=raw&hours=0&taf=off&layout=on&date=0

Comment: html code or url, please

Comment: </div>
<p clear="both">
<b>Data at: 0734 UTC 27 Jan 2017</b></p>
<!-- Data starts here -->
KJXN 270656Z AUTO 30012KT 10SM SCT026 OVC033 00/M04 A2980 RMK AO2 SNE0558 SLP100
  P0000 T00001044<br/><hr width="65%"/>
KTEW 270724Z AUTO 27008KT 10SM OVC040 00/M04 A2979 RMK AO2 T00001042<br/><hr width="65%"/>
<!-- Data ends here -->
<br clear="both" style="clear:both;"/>
</div> <!-- awc_main_content -->
</div> <!-- awc_main -->

Comment: @宏杰李  ^here it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests, bs4

r = requests.get('https://www.aviationweather.gov/metar/data?ids=KJXN%20KDTW%20KLAN&format=raw&hours=0&taf=off&layout=on&date=0')

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

text_list = soup.find(id="awc_main_content").find_all(text=True)
start_index = text_list.index(' Data starts here ') + 1
end_index = text_list.index(' Data ends here ')
text_list[start_index:end_index]
```

out:

```
['\nKJXN 270656Z AUTO 30012KT 10SM SCT026 OVC033 00/M04 A2980 RMK AO2 SNE0558 SLP100\n  P0000 T00001044',
 '\nKDTW 270653Z 28012KT 9SM -SN BKN020 BKN035 OVC065 02/M04 A2980 RMK AO2 SNB08\n  SLP095 P0000 T00171039',
 '\nKLAN 270653Z 27012KT 10SM OVC042 00/M05 A2979 RMK AO2 SLP096 T00001050',
 '\n']
```

`text_list` will return all the text in the `div` tag, we can use `index` to get the start and end index of info we need then slice the list.
[image]

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for.